# windows movie maker saving video without images

Tags: windows-7, windows-movie-maker

I'm trying to create a video from Windows Movie Maker, I've embedded sound & images from my laptop. The sample plays fine in WMM but when I try to save it in any video format, it creates a video without images (black window) with only sound.

Please help. Am I doing something wrong ? I've created videos earlier also and have never had such a problem.

Comment: Codec issue maybe? I don't know. Or maybe your file is "slightly corrupted" in a way, and WMM can still read it because it's its native format, while others can't. You could try to find some other software that allows you to import WMM source files and save them with that program.

Comment: Do the videos play in VLC?

Comment: yes the produced `black video` plays in VLC.